# Redirection of stdout in Python and/or sh

Tags: python, sh, stdout, io-redirection

I need to run my Python program from rc.local, backgrounded, sudo'd to a user account and nohup'd. But:

```
nohup sudo -u pi ~pi/doit.py >~pi/doit.out &
```

doesn't work because the shell applies the redirection to the whole command running under root, and hence the file gets created by root, not user pi as I want.

So I tried doing the redirection in the Python program. By way of example, I did:

```
#!/usr/bin/python    
import sys
import time    
sys.stdout = open('doit.out', 'w')
while True:
  print(time.ctime())
  sys.stdout.flush()
  time.sleep(1)
```

but this truncates the file on each print, even if I set the file open mode to append, and whether or not I include the flush() or run it with python -u.

So:
1. Why does Python keep truncatung the redirected stdout and how can I stop it?
or:
2. How can I get the redirection on the command line to operate on the command executed by nohup and sudo, rather than the whole command line?
or:
answers to both the above for my edification and enlightenment.

Regards - Philip

Comment: running your example does not reproduce the problem on ubuntu using python 2.7.6. It appends the lines. Specify your system in your question, please.
And try to sync the file by adding this line after the flush command `os.fsync(sys.stdout.fileno())`

Comment: This is on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Wheezy and Python 2.7.3. I'll try that os.fsync later. But that doesn't answer either of my questions.

Comment: OK, so the truncating problem has now gone away (without resorting to the os.fsync() ). Maybe I still had another backgrounded task which I'd failed to kill, running another version of my test program. I've rebooted since.

But I'd still quite like to know how to redirect stdout for the command being run by sudo rather than for sudo itself.

Comment: OK, people seem to have been focussing their brainwaves in my direction. This seems to work as an example:

`root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/staticisor# sudo -u pi bash -c "echo hello>file.out"`
`root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/staticisor# ls -l file.out`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 6 Feb 23 18:31 file.out`

Comment: (Sorry, just getting used to formatting in comments - time limit 4 mins.)
    Still not got it.  Looking for a sandbox to try this in . Soz folks - bear with me.